# Flutter: using nested navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page that divides the screen into left (`CheckOutPage`) and right (`MyFoodOrder()`):

```
class TakeOrderPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TakeOrderPageState createState() => _TakeOrderPageState();
}

class _TakeOrderPageState extends State<TakeOrderPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(flex: 4, child: CheckOutPage()),
        VerticalDivider(),
        Expanded(flex: 6, child: MyFoodOrder()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In `MyFoodOrder`, I have a widget that builds the food items using `FoodCard`:

```
  Widget buildFoodList() {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.count(
        //itemCount: foods.length,
        childAspectRatio: 3.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        controller: _controller,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        //children: foods.map((food) {
        //    return FoodCard(food);
        //}).toList(),
        children: [for (var food in Level1) if ((food.foodType == MyFoodTypes[value])) FoodCard(food)].toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Inside `FoodCard`, I have a widget that has an `InkWell` that can move to another page when tapped for selecting options. At the moment, the new page `ChooseOptions()` will occupy the whole screen:

```
  Widget buildPriceInfo() {
    ConfirmAction action;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '\$ ${food.price}',
            style: titleStyle,
          ),
          Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
            shape: roundedRectangle4,
            color: mainColor,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: IsAvailable() ? () async {
                remark = ''; //cancel any selected taste
                if (food.options.length != 0) {
                  if (food.options.containsKey('2')) {
                    action =  await _showTasteDialog(food.index);
                  }
                  if (food.options.containsKey('1')) {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ChooseOptions(food)),
                    );
                  }
                  else
                    addItemToCard();
                }
                else
                  addItemToCard();
              } : (){},
              splashColor: Colors.white70,
              customBorder: roundedRectangle4,
              child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 30,),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to modify it so that the new page of `ChooseOptions` only occupies the area of `MyFoodOrder()` instead of the whole screen. I read that nested navigator is the solution but I couldn't work it out after reading some of the examples online. Grateful if more explicit guidance or help can be provided.

Many thanks!

Comment: I suggest that, if you want to navigate to another Widget and keep what you can call "background", you will need to make a separate Widget for your background and then, upon navigating to `ChooseOptions`, only the body of the app changes. Furthermore, it makes it so that you will only need a few lines or even only 1 line of code to include the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your MyFoodOrder with **Navigator**, set the routes, and assign a Navigation Key to it.

```dart
static final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Then use the Navigation Key to changing the routing.

```dart
navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed("Your route");
```